# Can I use a Facebook Profile as the object in an Open Graph action?

Tags: properties, action, facebook-opengraph

I see that there is a `Profile` object type available in the OpenGraph. That's the same type that is used by the `tags` property of an action.

When I add a custom property of type `Profile` in one of my actions, Facebook expects for the objects to be web sites. Even if I pass the Facebook Profile ID, just as we can do with the `tags` property, the value is translated to a URI rather than pointing to a Facebook profile.

I want to be able to record statements such as `<Facebook User A> <my action> <my object> with/for/about <Facebook User B>`. The `with`, `for`, `about` are properties of the action.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say 'with' then add the UIDs of the tagged users in the tags property of the action.

If you want to say 'user 1  user 2' then link the action to a profile object type. The URL of the object should be a Facebook profile URI, for example

```
http://www.facebook.com/sicross
```

I you want to say: 'user 1  ' but then have another user as a custom property of the action, add a custom property of type 'profile' to the action, and use the Facebook user URI as before.

Custom action properties are useful to build awesome aggregaions, but they song get constructed into news feed story titles. Only using the tags param will give you other users names in the newsfeed title.

Comment: Thank you Simon,

It's the custom action property that I am trying to make work.

I declare a property called `"with"` of type `"profile"` for my action. It's the same type as that used for `"tags"`. When I POST an action, the property gets recorded as an object of type `"website"`.  

`"with": {  
  "id": "<id>",  
  "url": "http://www.facebook.com/<username>",  
  "type": "website",  
  "title": null  
}`  

That's the reason I posted the original question.

Obviously I am doing something wrong :-(